# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'category' into field. Choices are: id

Tags: python, django, python-2.x

Есть 2 базы данных, основная и старая. Нужно из старой базы записать данные в новую. Для новой базы был создан app, и в нем определены модели с помощью inspectdb. В файле local.py база определена под своим именем. Для неё был написан dbRouter. Проблема состоит в том, что когда я пытаюсь фильтровать данные в новой базе:

```
CatalogBrandCategories = apps.get_model('legacy', 'CatalogBrandCategories')
brandIdsQuery = CatalogBrandCategories.objects.filter(category__pk=72)
```

и когда я в качестве аргумента указываю поле типа ForeignKey при выполнении миграции выдается:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'category' into field. Choices are: id
```

Модель выглядит так:

```
class CatalogBrandCategories(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey('CatalogBrand', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    category = models.ForeignKey('BoardCategory', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'catalog_brand_categories'
        unique_together = (('brand', 'category'),)
```

Дополнительно ко всему, если я делаю все это в шелле, оно работает.

Уважаемые знатоки, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Проблему решил тем, что просто SQL запросами взял нужные данные из базы в миграции.